# Изменение данных при нажатии кнопки

Tags: java, swing, button

Работаю с `java swing`.
На мониторе отображаются данные с переменной `newDegree` (благодаря Thread конвертируются разные данные каждые 5 секунд).
Когда кнопка `jButton1` нажимается, то данные должны так же постоянно изменяться, но уже отображаться быть в формате фаренгейта `far`.
Пока удалось только сделать следующее: когда нажимается кнопка, то один раз отображается значение `far`. Однако далее опять `newDegree`. 
Задача в том, чтобы отображались значения `far`до тих пор пока не будет закрыта программа или нажата другая кнопка.

По сути программа просто выдает изменения температуры в цельсиях и должна при нажатии кнопки выдавать постоянно данные по Фаренгейту.

```
   private void heatSensor1HeatChanged(system.HeatChangedEvent evt) {                                        

   double newDegree = evt.getCelsius();
   String date = evt.getDate();

   monitor1.setText(String.valueOf(newDegree));

         far = newDegree;
         far = 9*far/5 + 32;

    System.out.println("F=============");
    System.out.println(far);
    System.out.println("F=============");

    System.out.println("C=============");
    System.out.println(newDegree);
    System.out.println("C=============");

}                                       

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    monitor1.setText(String.valueOf(far));

    // TODO add your handling code here:
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы сделал следующим образом.

1. Ввел бы дополнительную private boolean-переменную isTemperatureInCelcium (при значении true температура будет отображаться в цельсии, при false в фаренгейте).
2. В методе jButton1ActionPerformed по клику на кнопку просто меняется значение этой переменной.

   ```
   if (isTemperatureInCelcium) {
       isTemperatureInCelcium = false;
   } else {
       isTemperatureInCelcium = true;
   }
   ```
3. В методе heatSensor1HeatChanged, который, как я понял, запускается каждые несколько секунд просто выполнить проверку следующего рода и менять текст на мониторе в зависимости от значения переменной.

   ```
   if (isTemperatureInCelcium) {
       monitor1.setText(String.valueOf(newDegree));
   } else {
       monitor1.setText(String.valueOf(far));
   }
   ```

Comment: Спасибо, работает идеально. И почему я сама до такого не додумалась...